# how to set radio-group selection as ngmodel after changing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, radio-group, ngmodel

I m working with radio-group, for different ion-radio selection in different row i have used **ngModel**, that has been done. but when user changes its value, i have some conditions if the conditions are not matched then the selection should be done as it is using ngModel, but i'm unable to do so. i was looking for reload data or refresh data but what i have found as result is to refresh the page, i don't want to refresh the page. so i want to set selection of ion-radio as it is using ngModel, can anyone help me? my code is below....

```
<ion-list *ngIf="item.students && item.open" no-lines>
        <div *ngFor="let child of item.students; let j = index">

        <ion-label>{{ child.studentName }}</ion-label>

          <ion-row radio-group *ngIf="SelectToHome" [(ngModel)]="child.check" >
            <ion-col>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label>YES</ion-label>
                <ion-radio value="do"(ionSelect)="UpdatepuStatus($event,child);"></ion-radio>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label>Clear</ion-label>
                <ion-radio value="Clear" (ionSelect)="UpdatepuStatus($event,child);" ></ion-radio>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>

        </div>
    </ion-list>
```